# Modifying the XMPP Presence Stanza

Tags: xmpp

In XMPP user can send subscription request to another user to add in roster, I am easily doing this even working perfectly if user is offline server automatically dispatch this presence when user come online.

But I need to add a custom tag to this presence, it works till user is online, if user is offline the server send the regular presence without my custom tag when user arrives online.

How to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the XMPP server you are using does not store the extended info of the presence.
 According to  RFC6121 3.1.3.4 the server must store this info:
http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#sub-request-inbound

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am using jabber server.

Comment: "jabber" is an acronym for the XMPP protocol, not a server. Anyway, you should contact your server vendor.

Comment: sorry its ejabber server, sometimes this auto correct cause these misunderstanding :)

Comment: Notice, that this extended content is very limited and strictly defined: https://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#stanzas-extended Do you adhere to these restrictions?